# Paste "N/A" in Multiple Cells Based on One Cell's Value

Tags: vba, paste, cells

So I'm in need of a script that will do the following:

- If cell B2 = Duck, Then paste "n/a" in cells C2, D2, E2
- If cell B2 = Bear, Then paste "n/a" in cells C2, D2
- If cell B2 = Dog, Then paste "n/a" in cell C2

Additionally I need this rule to carry in the respective rows down to 500 (if cell B3 = Duck, Then C3, D3 and E3 are affected).

Thanks for the help! I do not have much experience in this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `=IF(OR(B2="Duck", B2="Bear", B2="Dog"),NA(),"")` and variants of that will do what you need

Answer (score 2):

Put this in C2 and copy over and down the list:

```
=IF(MATCH($B2,{"Dog","Bear","Duck"},0)>=COLUMN(A:A),NA(),"")
```

If you want the string `n/a` then put `"n/a"` in place of `NA()` in the formula

[image]

---

A vba solution:

```
Sub fillNA()

Dim lookupArr(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant
Dim i&, j&
lookupArr(1, 1) = "Duck"
lookupArr(1, 2) = 3
lookupArr(2, 1) = "Bear"
lookupArr(2, 2) = 2
lookupArr(3, 1) = "Dog"
lookupArr(3, 2) = 1

With ActiveSheet

    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = LBound(lookupArr, 1) To UBound(lookupArr, 1)
            If .Cells(i, 2) = lookupArr(j, 1) Then
                .Cells(i, 3).Resize(, lookupArr(j, 2)).Value = "N/A"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Range("B2") = "Duck" Then Range("C2,D2,E2")="n/a"
```